¿Cómo cambiar un pixel de color gris a color RGB?
me gustaría saber cómo puedo asignarle un color a un pixel pasando de escala de grises a color RGB. La idea es reasignar el color gris por un color RGB parecido al que tenia.
Restaurar-lo es imposible, pero, ¿De que manera puedo reasignarle otro color por escala RGB en vez de la escala de grises? Gracias de antemano.
Mi código es el siguiente


Public Sub ConvertirGrisAColorRGBDesdeColores(ByVal Imagen As PictureBox, Optional ByVal ViewProgres As Boolean = True)
    ' Convertir a Escala de Grises a Color con RGB

    On Error Resume Next

    Imagen1.Image = Imagen.Image.Clone
    Imagen2.Image = Imagen.Image.Clone

    Dim imAgtEmp1 As New Bitmap(Imagen1.Image)
    Dim imAgtEmp2 As New Bitmap(Imagen2.Image)
    Dim ElColor As Color = Color.Black

    Dim Hasta As Integer = imAgtEmp1.Height * imAgtEmp1.Width
    Progreso.Minimum = 0
    Progreso.Maximum = Hasta
    Me.Enabled = False

    If ViewProgres = True Then
        Me.Show()
        Application.DoEvents()
    End If


    For Arriba = 0 To imAgtEmp1.Height - 1
        For Izquierda = 0 To imAgtEmp1.Width - 1
            ElColor = imAgtEmp1.GetPixel(Izquierda, Arriba)

            Dim NumColor As Integer = ColorAGris(ElColor)

            Dim ElRojo As Integer = ElColor.R
            Dim ElVerde As Integer = ElColor.G
            Dim ElAzul As Integer = ElColor.B

            ElRojo = ((CInt(ElColor.R.ToString) / 3) / 0.08)     ' 0.08 es buena
            ElVerde = ((CInt(ElColor.G.ToString) / 3) / 0.16)    ' 0.16 es buena
            ElAzul = ((CInt(ElColor.B.ToString) / 3) / 0.24)     ' 0.24 es buena

            If ElRojo <= 0 Then ElRojo = 0
            If ElVerde <= 0 Then ElVerde = 0
            If ElAzul <= 0 Then ElAzul = 0
            If ElRojo >= 255 Then ElRojo = 255
            If ElVerde >= 255 Then ElVerde = 255
            If ElAzul >= 255 Then ElAzul = 255

            ElColor = Color.FromArgb(ElRojo, ElVerde, ElAzul)

            imAgtEmp2.SetPixel(Izquierda, Arriba, ElColor)

            If ViewProgres = True Then
                Progreso.Value = Progreso.Value + 1
            End If

        Next
        If ViewProgres = True Then
            Imagen2.Image = imAgtEmp2.Clone
            Imagen2.Refresh()
            Application.DoEvents()
        End If

    Next


    Imagen.Image = imAgtEmp2.Clone

    Me.Hide()

End Sub




Tienes un ejemplo? Puedes hacerlo en Paint o tu programa de edición de imagen favorito

El código que expongo, le aplica color en una imagen de escala de grises, lo que pregunto yo es si hay alguna forma mejor de aplicar ese filtro en base a 256 colores de grises para que se aplique a la salida un color RGB que no sea el gris si no que sea el color asignado por escala de ese color.

Bueno, cuando usas un shader cada componente del color está normalizada (en el rango de 0 a 1). Por lo tanto es fácil aplicar un tinte a una imagen en escala de grises, simplemente multiplicas el color por el tinte y obtienes una imagen en escala de ese tinte. Otra cosa que se me viene a la mente es contar con una paleta de colores y aplicarla según el color gris que estés usando. Una técnica similar se llama dithering.

Al final, esta parte del programa la he resuelto con esto:


Public Sub ConvertirGrisAColorRGBDesdeColores(ByVal Imagen As PictureBox, Optional ByVal ViewProgres As Boolean = True)
    ' Convertir a Escala de Grises a Color con RGB

    On Error Resume Next

    Imagen1.Image = Imagen.Image.Clone
    Imagen2.Image = Imagen.Image.Clone

    Dim imAgtEmp1 As New Bitmap(Imagen1.Image)
    Dim imAgtEmp2 As New Bitmap(Imagen2.Image)
    Dim ElColor As Color = Color.Black

    Dim Hasta As Integer = imAgtEmp1.Height * imAgtEmp1.Width
    Progreso.Minimum = 0
    Progreso.Maximum = Hasta
    Me.Enabled = False

    If ViewProgres = True Then
        Me.Show()
        Application.DoEvents()
    End If


    For Arriba = 0 To imAgtEmp1.Height - 1
        For Izquierda = 0 To imAgtEmp1.Width - 1
            ElColor = imAgtEmp1.GetPixel(Izquierda, Arriba)

            Dim NumColor As Integer = ColorAGris(ElColor)

            Dim ElRojo As Integer = ElColor.R
            Dim ElVerde As Integer = ElColor.G
            Dim ElAzul As Integer = ElColor.B

            ElRojo = ((CInt(ElColor.R.ToString) / 4.5) / 0.08)     ' 0.08 es buena
            ElVerde = ((CInt(ElColor.G.ToString) / 3) / 0.16)    ' 0.16 es buena
            ElAzul = ((CInt(ElColor.B.ToString) / 2) / 0.32)     ' 0.24 es buena

            If ElRojo <= 0 Then ElRojo = 0
            If ElVerde <= 0 Then ElVerde = 0
            If ElAzul <= 0 Then ElAzul = 0
            If ElRojo >= 255 Then ElRojo = 255
            If ElVerde >= 255 Then ElVerde = 255
            If ElAzul >= 255 Then ElAzul = 255

            ElRojo = (ElColor.R + ElRojo + ElRojo) \ 3
            ElVerde = (ElColor.G + ElVerde + ElVerde) \ 3
            ElAzul = (ElColor.B + ElAzul + ElAzul) \ 3

            ElColor = Color.FromArgb(ElRojo, ElVerde, ElAzul)

            imAgtEmp2.SetPixel(Izquierda, Arriba, ElColor)

            If ViewProgres = True Then
                Progreso.Value = Progreso.Value + 1
            End If

        Next
        If ViewProgres = True Then
            Imagen2.Image = imAgtEmp2.Clone
            Imagen2.Refresh()
            Application.DoEvents()
        End If

    Next


    Imagen.Image = imAgtEmp2.Clone

    Me.Hide()

End Sub



No logra colores originales, pero, la colorea más o menos bien.
Lo que hago para resolverlo es hacer primero una capa de coloración para mezclar con la capa gris después de haberla coloreado.
Así parece que eso funciona.
